# Multiple browser tabs with different sessions mvc

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, mvcrazor

This project allows for clients to insure various types of risk items (wheelchair/vehicle/scooter). For each risk item a different route was created (as different questions are asked for each type). Currently a risk item can be chosen and the client then fills in all their information, get a quote and then incept the policy (pay via credit/debit card). This application was created to only insure one risk item per policy. All of this works fine if a client only wants to insure one risk item. If the client then select to insure a different risk (or another) item a problem persist as the browser now holds the session of the previous request.

I need a to find a way to allow for different (or the same) risk items to be quoted and incepted without interfering with a previous policy inception (payment). 
When a client chooses a risk item (from a different website) it will navigate to the first start point of the risk item opening a different tab. Is it possible to maintain a session per tab?

This is what was done...

Register routes (File referenced to Global.asax)

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Scooter",
            url: "Scooter/{action}/{id}",                
            defaults: new { controller = "Mobility", action = "All", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Wheelchair",
            url: "Wheelchair/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Mobility", action = "All", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ComingSoon", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        BundleMobileConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //Add a required data annotation that relies on the value of another property to set the field as required
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredIfAttribute),typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
    }
```

Creating the sessions:

```
    #region Helpers
    private static T GetSession<T>(string key)
    {
        object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];

        if (value == null)
            return default(T);
        else
            return ((T)value);
    }

    private static void SetSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public static void ClearQuoteSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }

    public static string GenerateBuyMapCode()
    {
        var holderKey = Guid.NewGuid();

        var polMapCode = "BB-" + holderKey;

        return polMapCode.Trim();
    }
```

The following method allows for the sessions to be created with the cookie.

```
    public static PolicyBase CreateNewPolicyBase(Enums.RiskType type)
    {
        var polBase = new PolicyBase();
        polBase.Insured = new InsuredViewModel();
        polBase.RiskMeItems = new List<RiskItemMeModel>();
        *Irrelevant code removed*
        polBase.SessionKey = GenerateBuyMapCode();
        polBase.BrowserSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;

        *Irrelevant code removed*
        return polBase;
    }

    #region Session INIT
    public static string QuoteKey
    {
        get { return GetSession<string>("QuoteKey"); }
        set { SetSession("QuoteKey", value); }
    }
    public static AusEnums.RiskType RiskType
    {
        get { return GetSession<AusEnums.RiskType>("RiskType"); }
        set { SetSession("RiskType", value); }
    }

    public static AusEnums.QuoteArea Area
    {
        get { return GetSession<AusEnums.QuoteArea>("QuoteArea"); }
        set { SetSession("QuoteArea", value); }
    }

    public static PolicyBase PolicyBase
    {
        get { return GetSession<PolicyBase>("PolicyBase"); }
        set { SetSession("PolicyBase", value); }
    }

    public static SSMultiPremium MultiPremium
    {
        get { return GetSession<SSMultiPremium>("MultiPremium"); }
        set { SetSession("MultiPremium", value); }
    }
```

The web.config

```
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="20" />
```

The mobility and motor risk items have different start points, the following is the start point of the mobility (customer follows the principle)

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
    public ActionResult Insured()
    {
        //We need to determine the direction

        SessionHelper.GetRoutePath((Route)ControllerContext.RouteData.Route);
        var polBase = SessionHelper.PolicyBase;
        HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("BBCookieCheck");
        userCookie["Name"] = "BB";
        userCookie.Expires.AddDays(1); // cookie will expire after 1 days
        Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);

        var viewModel = new InsuredViewModel();
        if (polBase != null)
        {
            viewModel = polBase.Insured;
            viewModel.Title = polBase.Insured.Title;
        }

        viewModel.riskType = SessionHelper.RiskType;
       *Irrelevant code removed*
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Insured(InsuredViewModel model)
    {
        *Irrelevant code removed*
        //create a new quote object and save the relevant fields
        var polBase = SessionHelper.PolicyBase;
        if (model.Id == 0)
        {
            polBase = SessionHelper.CreateNewPolicyBase(model.riskType);
           *Irrelevant code removed*
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your use case might benefit from a [cookieless session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_SessionStateSection_Cookieless) state tracking. 
It also appears you are pretty much there.

```
    <sessionState cookieless="UseUri" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="20" />
```

[`UseDeviceProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookiemode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpCookieMode_UseDeviceProfile) pretty much means that any modern browser would resort to using cookies. But if you specifically lock it to `UseUri` your might get better results.

In this case your `GetSession<string>("XXX")` probably becomes redundant as each session would only relate to one policy flow